# Using cut -c option to cut a portion out of a line

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, scripting

My problem is trying to use the cut -c option only to cut the time from the date command
Right now I have this:

```
today=$(date)
echo The date right now is "$today"
echo The time right now is cut -c 11-18 $today
```

It cannot read it right now completely and I only want the time from this

Current output:

The date right now is Wed Apr 26 18:46:59 PDT 2017

The time right now is

Comment: Why not just ask the `date` command to only give you the time, rather than ask for content you don't want and have to modify it later?

Comment: If you have bash 4.3 or later, you can use shell-native built-in date formatting, which is even more useful (since you can capture the time only once and then format it in multiple ways).

Comment: our assignment specifically stated use the cut -c option but I do not understand how to use it!

Comment: *Oh*. So this is homework asking you to do things in a needlessly inefficient way. I should have known.

Comment: `echo "The time right now is $(printf '%s\n' "$today" | cut -c 11-18)"`

Comment: sorry :( I am fairly new to bash scripting

Comment: oh, I think I see. So the pipe command redirects the output from the console and allows you to cut that portion out?

Comment: (btw, re: using `printf` instead of `echo`, see the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, recommending `printf` instead for new development and describing portability problems with how `echo` is defined).

Comment: Eh? "From the console"? This code still works if there's no console (no TTY or terminal) involved at all.

Comment: also jsut wondering, the command that the date you were referring to would be date -R correct?

Comment: `printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' -1` will print the date with only bash builtins (no use of the external `date` command) in modern bash (4.3 or newer).

Comment: Thanks so much though Mr. Duffy

Comment: (ksh93 also has built-in date formatting -- indeed, it's the shell that many of bash's newer features are inspired by).

Comment: ohhh I see that is very intresting

Comment: If your `date` man page is anything like mine (mac os x), you won't find much information about the different format options. `man strftime` will show you the different formats available for you to use with `date`.

Comment: The main problem with `echo The time right now is cut -c 11-18 $today` is that `bash` doesn't know that the line consists of two commands. `cut` will be seen as a normal word that should be echoed. You need some syntax explaning that you are starting a new sub-command in the middle of the first command. The simpliest way is using `$(subcommand)` like the first echo in the answer of @paxdiablo, that is preferred above backtics like @signjing used.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the line to do this would be something like (taking into account that `cut` is one-based so the first character position you want is 12 rather than 11):

```
echo "The time right now is $(echo "${today}" | cut -c 12-19)"
```

But there's absolutely *no* need to resort to `cut`. Variable expansion in `bash` will do this just fine with substring extraction (zero-based, so 8 characters at position 11):

```
echo "The time right now is ${today:11:8}"
```

Comment: Heh. I was considering this a bad question (hence commenting as opposed to answering), but I think you've made a point that it can be helpfully answered.

Comment: Just wondering, if we take that time out of the date portion, it remains a string still right? How would I make it so it is an int and can be read in an if statement with -ge command?

Comment: @AbraJlkjl, that should probably have been a separate question but here we go - you would have to get rid of the colons: `mytime="1${today:11:2}${today:14:2}${today:17:2}"` will give you a string `1hhmmss` which you can them compare - note the leading `1`, this prevents `bash` from trying to interpret times before 10am as octal since they have a leading zero. So then, if you wanted to exit if it's after 3:22:33pm, just use `[[ ${mytime} -gt 1152233 ]] && exit`.

Comment: @paxdiablo I decided to use a new post as a new question-- wondering if you can take a look:

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
echo The time right now is `echo $today | cut -c 11-19`
```

Output will be:

```
The time right now is 10:44:47
```

Comment: Using unquoted tokens as arguments is ill-advised, unless you specifically want word-splitting and globbing applied. Your answer not only duplicates part of paxdiablo's answer, but does so in a less robust fashion.